# <Security/SecRequirement.h> Available on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, security

I'm trying to access the codesigning information of an application during runtime.  I know it's possible to gain access to that information on a Mac using SecRequirementRef.h, there's even a category for it [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/checking-code-signing-and-sandboxing-status-in-code/).

I'm looking for something similar on the iPhone, just to verify which codesigning identity was used for an application.

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for SecRequirement list it as being available on OS X 10.6+. So no, not available for iOS. If something similar exists I am unsure of though.

Comment: Yup, thanks for that.  I'm still hoping someone knows of a way to get that information on the iPhone without access to that header.